# Prove the following inequality??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, polynomials

Prove that
\begin{equation}
(1+k)^{p}<\frac{(1-k^{p+1})}{(1-k)},
\end{equation}
Here k,p $\in$ (0,1). I have proved this ineqality for p=1/2. The proof is as follows.
\begin{eqnarray}
(1+k)^{0.5}<\frac{(1-k^{1.5})}{(1-k)} \\
(1+k)^{0.5}<\frac{(1-\sqrt{k})(k+1+\sqrt{k})}{(1-\sqrt{k})(1+\sqrt{k})}\\
(1+k)^{0.5}(1+\sqrt{k})<(k+1+\sqrt{k})\\
\text{Geometric Mean}<\text{Arithmatic Mean}
\end{eqnarray},
However I am not able to show this inequality for p $\in$ (0,1) with k lying between 0 to 1. I have checked the inequality to hold numerically. Please have a look at it.

Comment: have you heard about Bernoulli's inequality?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I saw the inequality right now, don't know if it could be used here somehow. Do you think it would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed show it using Bernouilli's inequality. It states that for $x > -1$ and $0 < r < 1$, $(1 + x)^r < 1 + rx$. The given inequality can be rewritten as
$$
(1 - k)(1 + k)^p < 1 - k^{p + 1}.
$$
Applying Bernouilli's inequality to the LHS, we get
$$
(1 - k)(1 + k)^p < (1 - k)(1 + pk) = 1 - k - pk^2 + pk.
$$
If we can show that this is strictly less than $1 - k^{p + 1}$ or, equivalently, that
$$
k^p < 1 + pk - p,
$$
we are done. This follows however from $k^p = (1 + (k - 1))^p < 1 + p(k - 1)$ by Bernouilli's inequality.